# Is it legal to scrape reviews from courses on Coursera?

Tags: web-scraping

I have developed a web-app using Flask and deployed it on Heroku. It takes in the URL of a course as input, scrapes through the reviews, and then displays the number of negative and positive reviews using a Sentiment Analyser. (It is to be noted that I only scrape the reviews and not the personal details of any user.)

Here is the web-app: https://courseraanalyzer.herokuapp.com/

Is this legal?

(I think it is because I don't have to log in to access this data and there's no strict copyright on these reviews too.)

Comment: can you give a link to an example? (maybe a link?)

Comment: I have added the link of the web-app to the question.

Comment: If you need an answer to a legal question, you need to ask a lawyer.  And not just any lawyer you meet on the internet, but *your* lawyer.

Comment: What do you mean with "there's no strict copyright"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal questions are expressly off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Mark Ransom does bring up a good point, here's some general advice for scraping sites: You'll want to visit the site's `robot.txt` file, which in this case is https://www.coursera.org/robots.txt. You'll notice if you read it properly that in this particular case, the `/learn` pages are *not* disallowed (yet not explicitly allowed), so for respecting the `robots.txt` document, you should be good.

That being said, there sometimes are clauses that aren't written in the `robots.txt` file but are written in a legal section of the site, so a proper legal review would be ideal. I don't believe that to be the case here. Just make sure you don't scrape pages that are listed as `Disallow` though.